# Cake PHP controller/model issue

Tags: php, cakephp, model

I've been starting to develop an application in CakePhP. I've not used it before, other than the tutorials. So to be sensible and "idiot check" I've done some skeleton code and so far it's copy/pasta'd nicely into the code. However: I've hit a snag.

I've followed the naming conventions that cakePHP dictates for standard inheritance. 
What seems to be a correct implementation looks like it's falling back on defaults. Can anyone see a gotcha, or have any suggestions?

Controller -> app/controller/VenuesController.php

View -> app/View/Venues/view.ctp

Model -> app/Model/Venue.php

The controller and view seem to link up fine, and I'm able to manipulate vars/arrays as you'd expect.

For testing purposes, I'm testing by declaring this in the Model:

```
public static function VenueModelTest() {
 return true;
}
```

And I'm attempting to run it in the Controller as such:

```
Venue::VenueModelTest();
```

The error I get is as follows:

Error: Class 'Venue' not found
File: C:[...]\app\Controller\VenuesController.php
Line: 43

I've tried to debug: For example - I did a var_dump($this->Model) from within the controller (passed to the view), which simply prints NULL.
That makes me think there's some form of problem with the routing.

But can anyone see why?

Cheers in advance.
Rick

*EDIT: I can confirm that the model isn't loading. If I include:

```
$this->loadModel('Venue');
```

...at the right place in the controller, it works.

Obviously this isn't ideal... can anyone spy why it's not working?
Cheers
Rick

As requested, here's the main controller in full:

```
<?php

// Venue model
// /app/Model/Venue.php

class Venue extends AppModel // implements ModelInterface
{

    public static function VenueModelTest() {
     return true;
    }

}

?>
```

*Edit - added static due to a blonde copy paste issue. To reiterate this is a STATIC object (so should be accessible from anywhere - I think!) and the call is:

```
$venue = Venue::VenueModelTest();
```

And the error is as stated above.
Also - if you MANUALLY force the load of the model - it works.

Comment: What version of CakePHP? Have you tried `$this->Venue->VenueModelTest();` ?

Comment: Hi Dave - thanks for the quick response... Here's some *weird behaiour for you*.
If I use the loadModel = works.
If I dont = doesn't work.
If I add $this->Venue->VenueModelTest(); = Works.

So calling $this->model->VenueModelTest() seems to make it work...

Version of Cake I'm using is 2.2.2

Comment: Likely something w/ your class names- can you post the first line of the model and controller?

Comment: class VenuesController extends AppController
class Venue extends AppModel

Comment: did you try putting `var $uses = array('Venue');` at the top of your controller?

Comment: hmmm - that looks fine.   Try without the 'static'?

Comment: I just tried: `var $uses = array('Venue');` and then removed `static` - of course that means it's available in the controller, but I made a different call - `$venue = new Venue` and that also failed...

Comment: you don't need `$uses` or `new Venue`

Answer (score 0):

Please post your model file.

Ensure it uses the suffix .php not .ctp and that you haven't declared $this->name = 'xxxx';

Comment: Sure thing: here we go.
`<?php
// /app/Model/Venue.php
class Venue extends AppModel // implements ModelInterface
{

 public function VenueModelTest() {
  return true;
 }
 
}

?>`

*added to main question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

The model is being loaded automatically (you're naming conventions are spot on), it's just you're accessing it incorrectly:

In a controller you access Model methods like this:

```
$this->Model->action();
```

So in your case you would use:

```
$this->Venue->VenueModelTest();
```

Comment: Derp - I'm sorry.. this was a copy pasta error while I was debugging.
This is a static function -> have given you a +1 as a brownie point for spotting it tho! :)
... err I will when I get 15 reputation :)

Comment: Rick - This kinda seems like the EXACT suggestion I made as the first comment to your question. :)

Comment: '$this->Venue->VenueModelTest();' doesn't work - I was giving the reputation as he correctly spotted a copy/paste mistake from me.
To confirm: I can only get things working by manually loading the model, not through autoloading it.